# Is my exponential decay answer correct?

Tags: exponential-function

At 1pm a hospital patient is given a pill containing 60 units of antibiotic. By 2pm the units in the patient’s body has dropped by 15%.  By 3pm a further 15% of units remaining in the body is lost.  If this fall-off rate is maintained, find the number of units of antibiotic remaining at 6pm.

Here is my calculation:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fUfj.png)

When checking my answer with an online exponential decay calculator I get a different result.

Is my calculation and answer correct?

Comment: $60 \times \left[(0.85)^5\right]$ is certainly correct.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.